# button does not change color in my react material-ui. Why?

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, background-color

I wanted to change the color of my button in deep purple, but it doesn't work. Do you know why? I have inserted the theme in my js as follows:

```
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

here is my js, where I have my style and home component

```
const styles = theme => {
  return {
    root: {
      link: {
        display: "flex"
      },
      icon: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(0.5),
        width: 20,
        height: 20
      },
      flexGrow: 1,
      container: {
        backgroundColor: "",
        padding: "20px",

    margin: "40px 0px 0px 0px"
  },
  gridLeft: {
    backgroundColor: ""
  },
  gridRight: {
    backgroundColor: "",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  titleTypography: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    marginBottom: "20px",
    color: "white"
  },
  subtitleTypography: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    marginBottom: "20px"
  },
  titleButton: {
    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
    marginBottom: "20px",
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.info.dark
  }
}
```

};

And this is how I used it in my jsx:

```
<Button
          variant="contained"
          size="large"
          className={titleButton}
          component={Link}
          to="/register"
        >
          Get started
        </Button>
```

and here is my info color of my theme:

```
export const teechrTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: "#fff",
      main: "#fafafa",
      dark: "#e0e0e0",
      contrastText: "#fff"
    },
    secondary: {
      light: "#fff176",
      main: "#ffee58",
      dark: "#fdd835",
      contrastText: "#fff"
    },
    info: {
      light: "#7e57c2",
      main: "#673ab7",
      dark: "#5e35b1",
      contrastText: "#fff"
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could you post your `ThemeProvider` related code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello and thank you for asking your question.

First of all it is not clear to me how you are injecting/rapping your theme around your components,

First import the ThemeProvider and rap it around your components tree where you usually do all the routing.

It should like this in App.js

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

then rap components with

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
<Header/>
<Content/>
<Footer/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

This is how you you inject the theme into your components.

moving on to changing the color of your button, I have written a small react component for you that does change the color of your button. Here you go hope this helps :)

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  purpleButton: {

    backgroundColor: "#4a148c", // you can add your specific CSS here.

  }
}));

const PurpleButton = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.purpleButton} variant="contained"> Get started </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PurpleButton;
```

In the above example I used the following hook "const classes = useStyles()" to change the color of the button. I think that this is the problem because it is missing in your code.

Let me know if you need more clarification I'm happy to help.

Comment: Hi nadim95. Thank you so much for your clear explanation! With your help, I recognized that I included the titleButton in the root brackets of my theme, that was the mistake.